Error: HuggingFaceInstructEmbeddings initalization
`python
from langchain.embeddings import HuggingFaceInstructEmbeddings
instructor_embeddings = HuggingFaceInstructEmbeddings()

`
I am stuck at this error can't seem to resolve this:
'''
TypeError: INSTRUCTOR._load_sbert_model() got an unexpected keyword argument 'token'
'''
Please help! How do i resolve this?
I want to use HuggingFaceInstructEmbeddings for vectorizing my dataset but its not working

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
